# Let $p=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}{\frac{1}{x}}$. Is $f(x)=x$ continuous on $[0,p]$?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

I finished my introductory calculus class and just had this question in my mind when I was preparing for the exam (Engineering Math). My lecturer has never gone through this type of question when he was teaching the concept of limit, but he just told us that what you evaluate from the limit expression is 'very close' to the actual value of the expression. (For example, in his words, $p=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}{\frac{1}{x}}=+\infty\neq\frac{1}{0}$). According to this, $f(x)=x$ should be continuous on $[0,p]\implies[0,+\infty]$. But in reality, $f(x)=x$ is continuous on $[0,+\infty)$ but not $[0,+\infty]$. Is there something to do with the 'very close' thing to answer this type of question?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  I've edited the tags of your question because the tag algebra-precalculus is used for questions in elementary math before the learning of calculus.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For any topological space $X$ (so in particular also for $[0,\infty]$ if you know how to view it as a topological space), the identity $X\to X$ is continuous.

Comment: What is a topological space? I learned how to calculate limits, derivatives, and integrals in that course but never into this high-end stuff. Perhaps I will spend some time learning about it after the exam.

Comment: @Meow A space equipped with a collection of (open) sets closed under finite intersection and arbitrary union.  That's beyond an introductory course in a first undergrad couse in mathematical analysis for math major, but fun to learn if you've chosen a good book.  If you'll work with chemical engineering, you might want to know the geometry about the molecules.